# Logical operators or assignment in Perl cannot work?

Tags: perl

I want to check my variable $id is equal 497 or equal 200 ,
if $id not equal 497 or $id not equal 200 then mail,
but when i run the example as below, I set $id =497 by hand , but run the code ,it's print "not equal\n";

```
my $id = 497;
if($id != 497 || $id != 200)
   {
      print "not equal\n";
   }
else
  {
      print "equal , not to mail\n";
   }
```

Comment: If you're comfortable with mathematical logic notation, you might want to read about [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). They describe how a condition like “equal to 497 or equal to 200” must be negated. In Perl code: `!($x || $y) == !$x && !$y`, and `!($x && $y) == !$x || !$y`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says not equal because `$id != 200` is true.  `||` returns true if either operand is true.

You want to say:

```
if ($id != 497 && $id != 200)
```

so not equal is printed only when $id is neither 497 or 200.